# How to remove first comma in each line and replace it with space?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm not much familiar with bash scripting, but I want to do a simple process on my large text file. I need to eliminate first comma in each line and replace it with space.
Here is how my text file looks like :

```
CAK55580,GO:0004672,GO:0004674,GO:0004713,GO:0005524,GO:0006468
CAK55582,GO:0004672,GO:0004674,GO:0004713,GO:0005524,GO:0006468
CAK55583,GO:0007165,GO:0008603
```

I know that I can remove the first comma in each line using 
`sed -i.bak 's/,//' file`, but I don't know how to replace it with space.
Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 3):

The stuff between the final slashes is what to replace with.

```
sed 's/,/ /' file
```